# #define new DEBUG_NEW in stdafx.h

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I've noticed that several of our projects do the whole

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif
```

thing in their stdafx.h.

Will this memory leak detection work as intended when specified in the stdafx?

Comment: Why would that make a difference?

Comment: I thought I read once that it shouldn't be done.

I know at a high level how precompiled headers work and DEBUG_NEW works, but not enough at the low level to know if this will work successfully. I think my main concern is that DEBUG_NEW is supposed to indicate the file that the memory allocation occurred in and that precompiling this preprocessor directive into stdafx.cpp will not give the intended output.

Comment: @user715780 you could post this as an answer

Comment: what post? You may have forgotten the link

Comment: In your question you talk of `"stdafx.h"`, while in your comment you mention `"stdafx.cpp"`

Comment: stdafx.h is precompiled for the stdafx.cpp compilation unit. Its then reused for each other compilation unit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put it in stdafx.h. Doing so can give you undesired side effects.

Here's why.

In most cpp files, you have something like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <AcmeHeader.h>
#include "MyHeader.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif
```

Note that the redefinition of new is explicitly supposed to happen after all headers are included. If you define DEBUG_NEW in stdafx.h, then that definition will also be applied to AcmeHeader.h and MyHeader.h, which can cause problems with headers that try to redefine operator new.

I've also run into cases where I've wanted to remove the redefinition of "new" for just one or two files, but that's a rare situation.